# Date Calculation in Sql

Tags: sql

I wanted to calculate the date difference between term date and the effective in the same table. I was wondering if anybody can help me.

For example: I am trying to pull all the subscribers under a particular group who had coverage previously and got termed and again reinstated(active). So now I would like to see the gap between the termed date and reinstatement.

I would be extremely grateful if anybody can help me ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no first row or second row in a table, unless a column is used to specify the ordering.  You should edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: `01312015` isn't a date or a recognizable date string format. In almost all databases (except SQLite) dates are binary types without any format. Some databases use the `YYYYMMDD` to specify *date literals*, ie strings used to specify dates, eg `20180313`. Even if for some reason you wanted to save dates as text or numbers, the YYYYMMDD pattern is the one that should be use because it allows ordering. Any other shape would mix up dates from different months and even years